# Xamarin all OS: take a photo with CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm creating a project where I have to take a lot of pictures. In my previous project for iOS all are working fine. I'm using the same code for a new project for all platforms (iOS, Android and UWP).

When I take a photo on Android the stream is empty. In UWP when I try to open the page where I can take a photo, the application is blocked: after 3-5 minutes it's unblocked and I can take a photo.

I'm using a [James Montemagno MediaPlugIn](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) latest version.

The code is pretty simple

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the camera command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The camera command.</returns>
    public async Task ExecuteCameraCommand() {
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
                                new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions());

        if (file == null)
            return;

        byte[] imageAsBytes = null;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
            file.Dispose();
            imageAsBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        if (imageAsBytes.Length > 0) {
            var resizer = DependencyService.Get<IImageResize>();
            imageAsBytes = resizer.ResizeImage(imageAsBytes, 1080, 1080);

            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(()=>new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
            _images.Add(new GalleryImage {Source=imageSource,OrgImage=imageAsBytes});
        }
    }
```

Any helps or idea?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Enrico, have you tried the test sample: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/tree/257784b77b4a035fe185faa3b21e54cad6e574cb/tests/MediaTest/MediaTest.UWP Can you see the issue on your uwp device?

Comment: Hey, thank you. I wrote to him for more info.